# what is the difference between {% url url_name %} and {% url 'url_name' %} in django

Tags: django

I am not sure what is the difference between {% url url_name %} and {% url 'url_name' %}. Why is there such a difference. When to use what? Need some clarification on that... Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of django 1.5 `{% url url_name %}` would treat the argument as a context variable, whereas `{% url 'url_name' %}` would give you the url named 'url_name'. In prior versions, the latter syntax is wrong, and won't work.

Answer (score 3):

So if you are using django 1.4 and will migrate to newer versions later use this syntax `{% url 'url_name' %}` to get named url.

Note: you will have to add `{% load url from future %}` in each of your template where you will use above syntax.