# Reference a url with an id by name in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I want to reference a dynamic url in my templates using its name, but am not sure how to incorporate the object id. In other words, I want to reference "/products/98" in my template without having to hard code it (as my url patterns might change).

In my urls.py, I have:

```
url(r'^products/(\d+)/$', 'products.views.show_product', name='product'),
```

How do I name my pattern such that I can call {% url ??? %} in the template to get the correct item with a specified id. e.g.

```
{% for product in product_list %}
    <a href="{% url ??? %}">Product #{% product.id %}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

urls.py:

```
url(r'^products/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', 'products.views.show_product', name='product'),
```

template:

```
{% load url from future %}


{% for product in product_list %}

<a href="{% url "product" product_id=product.id %}">Product #{{ product.id }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Make sure your products.views.show_product view function takes product_id as a parameter.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot! Should've realized there would be a shortcut for this, but I couldn't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

Use `{% url product product.id %}`.

Comment: No problem. If you're using a version of Django that's >= 1.3, you'll want to use msc's answer (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#changes-to-url-and-ssi).

Comment: Noted, stumbled across [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255502/what-is-the-difference-between-url-url-name-and-url-url-name-in-dj) earlier.